# Classes interacting each other

Tags: python, class, tkinter, interaction

i wants to make one class interact in another through a function.
a button that when clicked, add 1. But when I make the interaction, there is an error saying that `Resources` has not been defined

this is what i'm tring, but nothing seens to happens

```
from tkinter import *


class Caracteristicas:

    def __init__(self,master):

        self.caracteristicas = Frame(master)
        self.caracteristicas.grid(row=1,column=0)

        self.forca = Label(self.caracteristicas, text='FORÇA FÍSICA')
        self.forca.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.show_forca = Label(self.caracteristicas,text='1')
        self.show_forca.grid(row=0,column=1)

        self.b_forca = Button(self.caracteristicas,text='+',command=self.ad_for)
        self.b_forca.grid(row=0,column=2)

        self.Forca = 1

    def ad_for(self):
        global Forca
        self.Forca += 1
        Vida = self.Forca + 10
        self.show_forca['text'] = self.Forca
        Recursos.show_ferimentos['text'] = Vida


class Recursos:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.recursos = Frame(master)
        self.recursos.grid(row=1,column=1)

        self.ferimentos = Label(self.recursos, text='FERIMENTOS')
        self.show_ferimentos = Label(self.recursos, text='10')

        self.ferimentos.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.show_ferimentos.grid(row=1,column=0)


ficha = Tk()
a = Caracteristicas(ficha)
b = Recursos(ficha)
ficha.mainloop()
```

I would like to know how to make the interaction between the `Characteristics`class and the`Resources` class

I managed to solve the previous problem however, another appeared. This is my main program, and the solution proposed does not work in this case.

```
from tkinter import *
from Caracteristicas import Caracteristicas
from Recursos import Recursos

ficha = Tk()
a = Caracteristicas(ficha)
b = Recursos(ficha)
ficha.mainloop()
```

in the case they are different documents to be used in the main

Comment: The last part of your question is in Portuguese. Please, update it, since this forum is meant to be English only.

Comment: change `Recursos.show_ferimentos['text'] = Vida` to `b.show_ferimentos['text']`

Comment: @HenryYik, thanks buddy, it worked. But could you tell me why the exchange?

Comment: `b` represents the instance of the class `Recursos` you created, while `Recursos` is only a reference to the class `Recursos`.

Comment: Thanks @HenryYik, but another problem appeared. Can you help me? check the case, i've updated

Comment: if you have new problem then create new question. It is not forum. Here you put one question on page.

Comment: you should put on instance as argument in another class `Recursos(ficha, a)` and assing it in `__init__` to variable which you will use in another methods. Or assing it directly `b.other = a` and use `self.other` in all methods in instance `b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have instances of two classes and you need function in one of them to modify data or call methods on the other, you usually will want to pass a reference to the other object into the one that is going to interact with it.

In your code, that probably means you should pass your reference to the `Recursos` instance into the constructor of you `Caracteristicas` object, where it can be used later.

Here's a very abbreviated version of what that could look like:

```
class Caracteristicas:
    def __init__(self, master, resource):
        self.resource = resource    # save value for later
        ... # the rest of the constructor can be the same

    def ad_for(self):
        self.Forca += 1
        Vida = self.Forca + 10
        self.show_forca['text'] = self.Forca
        self.resource.show_ferimentos['text'] = Vida   # main change is here!
```

You also need to change the code where you create your objects, to something like:

```
b = Recursos(ficha)
a = Caracteristicas(ficha, b) # pass the reference to the resource object in
```